# Visual Studio Installer Project doesn't include my software exe

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje, vs-installer-project

I wrote a C# windows desktop software. I added an installer for it. The problem is the Setup project only includes a dll of my software in its Primary output, it doesn't include my software exe.

My Visual Studio is Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.3.6.

Microsoft .Net Framework Version 4.8.09032

I add the setup project as the following steps:
Right click on the Solution -> Add -> new project -> Search Setup -> Setup Wizard

Next

Fill a setup project name

Create

Setup Wizard

Next

Create a setup for a Windows application

Next

Select "Primary output from MyAppName"

Next

Next

Finish

The main properties of my software project:

In the Application section:

Output type: Windows Application

Target framework: .Net 6.0

Target OS: Windows

Target OS version: 7.0

Enable Windows Forms for this project.

Assembly name: $(MSBuildProjectName)
MySoftwareName

In the Build section:

Output:

Base output path: bin\

Base intermediate output path: obj\

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Point it to the release mode and rebuild the setup. You can check the release folder and msi will be created. You can install it and check in the installation folder where you will have windows forms with the exe's. You can create a shortcut to the desktop as well in the installer setup.

If you could post the video link for reference, I can tell you the corrections that are to be made.

Comment: For a .NET5+ project, the project.dll file *is* the primary output.  Runnable with the dotnet.exe host.  If you want to also copy the project.exe apphost file then right-click Application Folder > Add > File.

Comment: thank you for your help. How to "Point it to the release mode"? I made my software build to release folder. I rebuild the setup project; it doesn't fix the problem.  I checked the KeyOutput of Primary output properties. The  
SourcePath is pointed to program folder\obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\myApp.dll, I think it is wrong place. It should be bin\debug or bin\release. But the SourcePath cannot be changed. I feel the setup project is for web application, rather than windows form application.